# How do i creat a 2D bit array in java where data stored in each cell is of size 1 bit on hard drive?

Tags: 2d, bitarray

What I really want to accomplish is as follows:
1) Creat a table or packed 2D bit array, 2 columns--rows can be any lenght.
Give column names so I can reference them.
3) I can then set the individual bits in this array
4) Once data is put into the table, I want to write the table object to file.
I'm not concern about the size of the table object in memory as lons as data in each cell occupies 1 bit on hard drive. Let's say the table object is of size 10 bytes and i stored 16 bits in the table, so when written to files I get total of 12 byte.

I'm new to programing so please excuse me if I'm not making it clear.
I appreciate your knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

Any 2D array can be implemented using 1D array. Take an example of 2D array of m rows and n columns. In that case, size of equivalent 1D array would be m*n.

2D[i, j] would be equivalent of 1D[i*n + j]. Here i is row index and j is column index.

In java you use BitSet for implementing 1D Bit Array. BitSet Class is a serializable class and so you would be able to save it in disk. Some more research may be needed on how much space it eventually takes when you save a bitset object in harddisk.

Comment: Thanks a lot Niraj for your ideas. I have read a bit on BitSet, will do more research on the subject to see what comes up.

Answer (score -1):

You can't save one bit on the hard drive.

For instance I thing that char datatype in java occupies 4 bits, and thats is the simples datatype you can use.

Comment: Read about BitArray concept. It is possible to save 16 bits in 2 bytes as being asked. Yes, 17 bits will take 3 bytes but again 24 bits will ask the same memory.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Actually I'm not trying to save 1 bit to the hard drive. I want the data stored in the array index to be 1 bit each. So once I write the array object to file, the program designate the memory size of the primitive type plus its contect, which is 1 bit* n bits, depending on the number of rows. This array should have only two column. Thanks.